# mongodb cluster:after use keyFile for authentication ,it report socket exception for shard

Tags: mongodb, authentication, sharding

I use mongodb --keyfile parameter to config a authenticated mongodb cluster.Yes, I at first add an admin user to admin db without the authentication ,and then ,I restart the mongodb with --keyFile.Yes, after that , the authentication takes effect.But when I tried to addUser() or show dbs or show collections or db.collection.find(), it reports error:
mongos> db.system.users.find()

```
error: {
        "$err" : "socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for shard4/192.168.10.10:10004,192.168.10.12:10004",
        "code" : 11002,
        "shard" : "config"
}
```

sometimes, it is shared1,sometimes it is shard2 or shard3...

I checked every shard heath(I have 3 shards ,each shard have 3 replication set), all shard member's health status is 1,namely ok.

So ,any one can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I checked the log on /var/data/master/log.log, it said:
the permission of keyfile is too open.That means,I shouldn't have given such a file too high permission.So ,I run command below for every mongodb cluster member:

```
sudo chmod 700 /var/data/keyfile
```

And I checked the log again , the permission problem solved,but the socked exception error remains.

But I can ping to these config server net port successfully,it proves that actually these config server is working properly.

So ,why these config server cannot be connected ? Finally I get the reason: it is because I firstly start the mongos process and then the 3 config servers' mongod instance .When mongos is started ,  it is trying to connect to the config server ,but the config server is started afterwards,so ,it cannot reach them.Only when I started these 3 config server at first and then started the mongos instance ,problem solved!